# Text garbled when iText 7 extracts a character string

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I would like to extract a string from Japanese PDF.
However, it comes out garbled.
How can I do this, or what am I doing wrong?

```
iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil.AddToResourceSearch("itext.font_asian.dll");
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
using (var doc = new PdfDocument(reader))
{
    var rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 800, 800);

    var filter = new TextRegionEventFilter(rect);

    var pageCount = doc.GetNumberOfPages();

    for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
    {
        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextEventListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
        var page = doc.GetPage(i);
        var str1 = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
    }
}
```

Visual Studio 2015
C# .NET framework 4.6.1
iText7 (7.0.4 from Nuget)
iText.font-asian (7.0.4 from Nuget)

**PDF File :** [Japanese_PDF.pdf](https://mega.nz/#!c0YxARDS!sbcg00pbdZCkp2ULl2MtJ5x6wn-ISYq-HpZR0ginZIM)

Comment: Garbled as in "I am using the wrong encoding when I look at the string?" Or garbled as in "I get the same garbled result when I copy/paste the text from a PDF viewer?" Your question is too incomplete to answer. Show us the PDF. Do the fonts have a toUnicode map? (If these questions are too hard for you to answer, we *really* need to see the PDF so that we can check for ourselves.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.And I am sorry that my question is bad.  
The PDF file was written as a link, but I edited it for clarity. (Can you download it?)  

About Copy and Paste: I can select a character string from the PDF displayed in Acrobat Reader and paste it in Notepad.  

I will investigate the encoding from now.  
Can toUnicode map be obtained from PdfDocument (PdfPage?)? I will investigate this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing everything right. The text extraction functionality indeed had a problem for some CID fonts up until `7.0.4`. Now in `7.0.5-SNAPSHOT` this is fixed and the issue is no longer reproduced.

The NuGet packages with the current snapshot version can be downloaded from [artifactory](https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/simple/General/nuget).

Comment: Thank you very much.
It was confirmed that it can be extracted normally with 7.0.5-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Hi Alexey @Alexey, I'm trying to use the above lines of code, when GetTextFromPage method is called, it is throwing an exception like "The CMap iText.IO.Font.Cmap.UniJIS-UTF16-H was not found.". Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @DadapeerPvg have you added the font-asian package dependency?

Comment: Yes it was added before but still it was throwing that exception. I re-installed the packages from nuget package manager and then the issue got resolved.